# Issues in formulating a left_join query in rails5 / mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

There are three tables in DB. 
First, users having id.
Second, items having id,
Third, user_actions having user_id, item_id, is_deleted.

```
#Item
has_many :user_actions
#User
has_many :user_actions
#UserAction
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :item
```

User_actions entry is only when a user selects delete option. Otherwise, the user has no entry in user_actions table for that item.

I have to write a query to get all items for a user which he has not deleted.
I tried using left_join in rails5 but I couldn't get it to work right.

Some information that I did not convey before(my apologies).

- Items are unique. Assume we are getting it from a source like all posts on Facebook.
- There are lots of users being added and deleted, like in a subscriber list.
- All items are visible to all users unless the user deletes it for himself. Item still exists and is visible to other users who can act independently.

**We need a solution to solve this problem, where we can query and get all items which user has not deleted.**

Comment: Even when it 'doesn't work right', we still like to see it

Comment: Are you trying something like has_many and :through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your models are like:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_actions
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_actions
end

class UserAction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end
```

you are probably missing an association between `User` and `Item`.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_actions
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  has_many :user_actions
end
```

and of course running the migration to add the `user_id`column in `items` table

Then you could do something like:

```
your_user     = User.find your_user_id
deleted_items = UserAction.where(user: your_user).map(&:item).map &:id
items         = Item.where(user: your_user).where.not(id: deleted_items)
```

But without more information is hard to guess

Comment: Please read my edits, if you need any other information do let me know.